# How do I disable lens flare in The Evil Within?

Tags: pc, the-evil-within

After disabling post-processing with the `r_skipglare 1` console command, lens flare is still used.

[image: screenshot of lens flare in The Evil Within]

[image: screenshot of lens flare in The Evil Within]

[image: screenshot of lens flare in The Evil Within]

Answer (score 1):

From some quick research around Google, it would appear that no, you can't disable the lens flare in game. In fact, while researching, this question was the first link to appear on the results page. It would seem that it is not supported in the console to disable it, either, as [evidenced by this list of in-game console commands.](http://theevilwithin.gamepedia.com/PC_Console_Commands)

Comment: I've read through the console commands. No native way doesn't mean that lens flare can't be disabled, a lot can be done by modifying game texture files. Finding the right file will take time, unfortunately.

Comment: @user598527 Well, as the original scope of your question states, you were only asking about a console command.

Comment: I weren't asking about consoles commands, I only mentioned that there's a command that removes most post-processing effects.